# error trying to open pin image onclick in a modal with ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

issue is that the image inside the modal is always the first image displayed no matter what image I click on.

app/views/pins/index.html.erb

```
    <!-- pins -->
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">

        <!-- want to open a pin image onclick in a modal -->
        <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), "#showModal", :class => "btn", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>

        <!-- modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="showModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <%= image_tag pin.image.url %>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                <%= pin.description %><br/>
                <p><strong><%= pin.user.name if pin.user %></strong></p>
                <% if pin.user == current_user %>
                  <%= link_to edit_pin_path(pin), class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                  Edit
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path, class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= pin.description %><br />
        <%= pin.user.name if pin.user %><br />
        <% if (pin.user == current_user) or current_user.try(:admin?) or current_user.try(:king?) %>
          <%= link_to edit_pin_path(pin), class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            Edit
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to pin, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            Remove
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<!-- pages -->
<div class="center">
  <%= will_paginate @collection, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

I originally had the selected pin show up on a separate page onclick (working). Now i am trying to convert this page into a modal.
app/views/pins/show.html.erb

```
<div class="showbox">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <%= image_tag @pin.image.url %> <br/>
            <p>
                <%= @pin.description %><br/>
            </p>
            <p><strong><%= @pin.user.name if @pin.user %></strong></p>
            <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
                <%= link_to edit_pin_path(@pin), class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    Edit
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path, class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
      if @pin.save
        redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' 
      else
        render :new 
      end
  end

  def update 
    respond_to do |format|
       if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully destroyed.'  }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: 'Not Authorized' if @pin.nil?
    end

    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

Comment: did you try removing the `@` `<%= image_tag pin.image.url %>`

Comment: yes, but it then complains about the next @pin being called.

Comment: you need to call `<%= image_tag pin.image.url %>`  and `<%= pin.description %>`

Answer (score 0):

`undefined method 'image' for nil:NilClass` means that either one of your objects inside @pins array or the @pin variable are a nil. What it means is that you expect that an object will return for example `@pin = Pin.find(1)`, but what happens is that in the `pins` tables there is no row where `id = 1` so you have to check why is that.

Comment: I added my controller code for viewing as well as the working show page that i want to convert into a modal. I am starting to think that something is missing from this controller file. That the pin is not being set. Not sure how I would deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

In your *app/views/pins/index.html.erb* you are calling `<%= pin.description %>`

You need to do the same in your app/views/pins/show.html.erb, change `<%= @pin.description %>` to `<%= pin.description %>`.

Also, make sure you change `<%= image_tag pin.image.url %>`.

Comment: Ok, so I changed all the @pin to pin in the modal. Still complaining about pin being undefined. So I moved the modal code inside the loop underneath the link_to image_tag. No more errors and the modal is showing! Only issue is that the image inside the modal is always the first image displayed no matter what image I click on. The show page no longer exists. I was showing it to show how I was able to display the images on a different webpage by themselves. I update the code above